# WP Rest API get post by slug with special characters (ex: !&')

Tags: wordpress, rest, api

I have posts with slugs with special characters. One of them is the following:
http://localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?slug=my-post!

Unfortunately, WP REST API not showing the content since it has (!) within the slug.

Is there any solution you guys would recommend?

Comment: How did you enter that `!` in slug? Normally when you do, wp removes it on save

Comment: I was given this database with such a case. If it was just a few posts I would fix the posts, unfortunately, there are almost tons of them.

Comment: I have a similar issue but my character is `’`. Apparently accessing the post through the API calls [this function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_parse_slug_list/) which removes the special characters, but accessing through the normal view doesn't (so the character is allowed). In my case is indeed an old project so probably new posts can't have these special chars (my guess). I'll post an answer if I ever find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution (at least for my case), not sure if it'll work for you but may indicate you the way to go. We need to tap into the function used to sanitize the slugs, as I said in my comment, by default is [wp_parse_slug_list](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_parse_slug_list/). Looking at the code the function that actually sanitizes the slug is [sanitize_title](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_title/).

Looking at the source code, `wp_parse_slug_list` calls `sanitize_title` with only one argument, which means that the context used is `save`. This means that, for posts that were already saved without being sanitized by this function, the slug won't match and the post will be inaccessible through the API. The solution is to change the sanitizing function slightly by adding a filter:

```php
add_filter('rest_post_collection_params', function($query_params) {
    $query_params['slug']['sanitize_callback'] = 'sanitize_rest_api_slug';

    return $query_params;
}, 20, 1);

function sanitize_rest_api_slug( $list ) {
    if ( ! is_array( $list ) ) {
        $list = preg_split( '/[\s,]+/', $list );
    }

    foreach ( $list as $key => $value ) {
        $list[ $key ] = sanitize_title( $value, '', 'query' );
    }
    return array_unique( $list );
}
```

The filter is actually being applied on the function `get_collection_params()` on the `class-wp-rest-posts-controller` class, but if you look at the [source code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.6/src/wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-posts-controller.php#L2811), the filter has a variable depending on the `post_type`, so if you have another special kind of posts defined (besides `post`) you need to add/change a filter for that kind as well.

I hope this helps somebody else like me, even if it's too late for your issue.